# I want to create a script so that I don't have to type su and password every time

Tags: su

I want to create a script so that I don't have to type `su` and the password for logging into root every time.

Comment: I think you need to clarify exactly what you are aiming for. You could, but I don't recommend it, use sudo, and disable the password for sudo.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to allow an user to become root without entering a password, you should a least make sure that the capability is restricted to a particular user or an exclusive group.

You can use [`sudo`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudo) to allow running certain commands without entering a password. Edit `/etc/sudoers` file with the command `visudo` and add something like the following line:

```
 %wheel    ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/su
```

This example will allow users in the `wheel` group to execute `sudo su` without entering a password.

If you want to do this because you regularly execute particular commands as root, I'd suggest adding `sudoers` rules for just those commands instead to minimize the exposure of privileges.

Comment: got it.. using expect scripting i was able to run..